# (#210) User not visible

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I'm writing a facebook app in which the logged in user (a) chooses a friends from their friends list (b) and then the app posts on their friends wall (a posts to b).

I ask from the user the `publish_stream` permissions.
This is the code for showing the friends selector popup:

```
function selectFriends() {
FB.ui({
         method: 'apprequests',
         message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'
       },function(response) {
        if (response && response.request_ids) {
           //alert(typeof(response.request_ids));
           //alert(response.request_ids);
           alert (response.request_ids);
           len=response.request_ids.length;
           alert(len);
            if (len>2) {
                   alert("Select no more than one friend");
            }
            else {
                 user_req_id = response.request_ids[0];
             postOnFirendsWall(user_req_id);
                    }
            } 
        else {
           alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       });
    }
```

This is the `postOnFirendsWall(user_req_id)` method:

```
function postOnFirendsWall(friend_id)
{
    /** Auto Publish **/

    var params = {};
    params['message'] = 'message';
    params['name'] = 'name';
    params['description'] = '';
    params['link'] = 'https://www.link.com/';
    params['picture'] = 'http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203550_189420071078986_7788205_q.jpg';
    params['caption'] = 'caption';

    var stam = '/'+friend_id+'/feed';
    FB.api('/'+friend_id+'/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
        alert(response.error);
      } else {
        alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
      }
    });

    return false;
}
```

But I keep getting the following error: (#210) User not visible.

Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that user A has permission to write on the wall of user B? If not, this will never work.

Also, why are you using an apprequests dialog if you want to post on a friend's wall?

Comment: Igy: I tried to post on several friends wall and got the same error. Which dialog should I use instead?